# Posting jQuery var to PHP file and set cookie

Tags: php, jquery, post, var, setcookie

I am running this function on `document ready`:

`var datum_hoofdafspraak` is for example: `12 maart 2020`

```
setTimeout(
function() {
  var datum_hoofdafspraak = $(".bookly-cart-primary td:nth-child(2)").html();
  console.log(datum_hoofdafspraak);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/datum.php',
      data: datum_hoofdafspraak,
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function() {
       console.log("Datum sent to datum.php");
      },
    });
 }, 500);
```

It logs the success function.

The `datum.php` file is like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Check if request method is post
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If you wanna modify key text, you may do so like this:
    switch ($key) {
      case 'datum':
        $cookie_key = 'ingevoerde_datum';
        break;

      default:
        $cookie_key = $key;
        break;
    }
    // Saves cookie for half an hour on this domain
    setcookie($cookie_key, $value, time()+1800*1, "/");
  }
}

echo "Date is: " . $_COOKIE['ingevoerde_datum'];

?>
```

When navigating to datum.php I only get to see 'Date is: '.

Have I done something wrong?

SOLVED:
I fixed the problem myself.
didn't mention a name for using this for the `switch` in my `datum.php` file.

Changed this:

`data: datum_hoofdafspraak,`

to this

`data: { datum: datum_hoofdafspraak },`